# Create different shape in corona sdk?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application I have to use different shaped curve for my fonts. If it is possible to create different shape. Shapes like curve like that.. I have to crate graffiti font in corona like:http://www.graffiticreator.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Text Candy!
http://www.x-pressive.com/TextCandy_Corona/